# OpenCV C++ code to Obj-C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I was suggested an algorithm to prepare an image for OCR, the code giving to me is great! However it is not compatible with the iOS build of OpenCV it seems, there are a few different naming conventions and I am having a hard time converting the code to Obj-C++.
Could someone rewrite it for Obj-C++?

Here is the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "fstream"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CalcBlockMeanVariance(Mat& Img,Mat& Res,float blockSide=21) // blockSide - the parameter (set greater for larger font on image)
{
    Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I,CV_32FC1);
    Res=Mat::zeros(Img.rows/blockSide,Img.cols/blockSide,CV_32FC1);
    Mat inpaintmask;
    Mat patch;
    Mat smallImg;
    Scalar m,s;

    for(int i=0;i<Img.rows-blockSide;i+=blockSide)
    {       
        for (int j=0;j<Img.cols-blockSide;j+=blockSide)
        {
            patch=I(Range(i,i+blockSide+1),Range(j,j+blockSide+1));
            cv::meanStdDev(patch,m,s);
            if(s[0]>0.01) // Thresholding parameter (set smaller for lower contrast image)
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=m[0];
            }else
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=0;
            }           
        }
    }

    cv::resize(I,smallImg,Res.size());

    cv::threshold(Res,inpaintmask,0.02,1.0,cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg,CV_8UC1,255);

    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask,CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, INPAINT_TELEA);

    cv::resize(inpainted,Res,Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    namedWindow("Img");
    namedWindow("Edges");
    //Mat Img=imread("D:\\ImagesForTest\\BookPage.JPG",0);
    Mat Img=imread("Test2.JPG",0);
    Mat res;
    Img.convertTo(Img,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);
    CalcBlockMeanVariance(Img,res); 
    res=1.0-res;
    res=Img+res;
    imshow("Img",Img);
    cv::threshold(res,res,0.85,1,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::resize(res,res,cv::Size(res.cols/2,res.rows/2));
    imwrite("result.jpg",res*255);
    imshow("Edges",res);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

My attempt: (gives back blue image with black spots)

```
void CalcBlockMeanVariance(cv::Mat& Img,cv::Mat& Res,float blockSide=21) // blockSide - the parameter (set greater for larger font on image)
{
    cv::Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I,CV_32FC1);
    Res=cv::Mat::zeros(Img.rows/blockSide,Img.cols/blockSide,CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat inpaintmask;
    cv::Mat patch;
    cv::Mat smallImg;
    cv::Scalar m,s;

    for(int i=0;i<Img.rows-blockSide;i+=blockSide)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<Img.cols-blockSide;j+=blockSide)
        {
             patch=I(cv::Rect(j,i,blockSide,blockSide));
            cv::meanStdDev(patch,m,s);
            if(s[0]>0.01) // Thresholding parameter (set smaller for lower contrast image)
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=m[0];
            }else
            {
                Res.at<float>(i/blockSide,j/blockSide)=0;
            }
        }
    }

    cv::resize(I,smallImg,Res.size());

    cv::threshold(Res,inpaintmask,0.02,1.0,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    cv::Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg,CV_8UC1,255);

    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask,CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, CV_INPAINT_TELEA);

    cv::resize(inpainted,Res,Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res,CV_32FC1,1.0/255.0);

}
```

Calling the method.

```
_img = [self cvMatFromUIImage:_endImage];
cv::cvtColor(_img, _img, CV_RGB2GRAY);
_img.convertTo(_img, CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
CalcBlockMeanVariance(_img, _res);
_res = 1.0 - _res;
_res = _img + _res;
cv::threshold(_res,_res,0.85,1,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
cv::resize(_res,_res,cv::Size(_res.cols/2,_res.rows/2));

_endImage = [self UIImageFromMat:_res];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply separate your c++ code in an another `NSObject class` and rename the filename to **OpenCVUtilities.mm** from **OpenCVUtilities.m**. **`mm`** suggests Objective -C should use C++ complier for the class and you don't need to convert the code to Objective-C for that, it will work as it is.

And after doing this you will need to change few settings in your **Project -> Build Settings** as shown in the image below

[image]

[image]

For more assitance you can download the project from [here](https://github.com/Jazmann/shared)

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am currently compiling in a .mm file and updated the build settings and I still get many errors, it seems as if the naming convention for the iOS framework is slightly different. I'll update my post with a few pictures.

Comment: Check with sample iOS applications and the link I provided, it all you need correct build settings and all required framework to be included, it should work..

Comment: Ok I see some good sample code, was there supposed to be an Xcode project? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Oh, I just needed to put `using namespace cv;` at the top of my file. *facepalm*